# How can I generate a HmacSHA256 signature of a string

Tags: php, hmac

Is there any way to create a HmacSHA256 signature of a string in php?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Use [`hash_hmac`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php):

```
$sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $string, $secret);
```

Where `$secret` is your key.

Comment: what's inside $string?

Comment: @MahaDev Whatever you want the signature of.

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm will hash_hmac will always generate unique string...?

Comment: @usama No. By the very nature of a hash function, there will exist a collision. (I.e. two strings that hash to the same value.) I suggest you look into hash collisions. The subject is too long to cover in a comment.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianPaaskeTørholm  for answer can you please explain in general how we can make it unique Thanks again.

Comment: I also want to iterate it to make hash even harder.

Answer (score 23):

The [**`hash_hmac()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) function could help, here :

> Generate a keyed hash value using the
>   HMAC method

For example, the following portion of code :

```
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', 'hello, world!', 'mykey');
var_dump($hash);
```

Gives the following output :

```
string '07a932dd17adc59b49561f33980ec5254688a41f133b8a26e76c611073ade89b' (length=64)
```

And, to get the list of hashing algorithms that can be used, see [**`hash_algos()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php).

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example of **datatrans transaction signing** (swiss e-payment solution) before call PSP with **HMAC-SHA-256**.

Hope it could help some developers.

```
$hmacKey    = 30911337928580013;

$merchantId = 1100004624;
$amount     = $total * 100;
$currency   = 'EUR';
$refno      = $orderId;

// HMAC Hex to byte
$secret     = hex2bin("$hmacKey");

// Concat infos
$string     = $merchantId . $amount. $currency . $refno;

// generate SIGN
$sign       = bin2hex(hash_hmac('sha256', $string, $secret));
```

*Note: the merchant ID and HMAC key are both from Datatrans documentation available here : https://admin.sandbox.datatrans.com/showcase/doc/Technical_Implementation_Guide.pdf*

Comment: Note that the bin2hex at the end will produce a different result than the example shown in the Datatrans backend UI!

Comment: Hi, I want to generate datatrans sign in javascript. But i am not able to achieve that. Do you have any working example for that.

Comment: @VinitSingh no I don't. But you can read this, maybe it will help you : https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#js

Answer (score 4):

This is the way. How to generate hash_hmac in laravel. It'll work 100%.

```
$sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $request->getContent(), 'secret value' );
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer due to lack of reputation, but @Melomans way in combination with ZPiDER's answer leads to using only

```
$hash       = hash_hmac('sha256', $string, $secret);
```

for a correct Datatrans signing

Answer (score 2):

okay to sign your data with hash_hmach
all you need is to do the following

1. get your secret key
2. choose a cipher mode or method example sha1,sha256, etc
3. create a variable that will hold your encrypted data call it whatever you like
   Therefore the code will look like this

```html
$signData= hash_hmac("sha256",$dataToBeSigned,$yourSecretKey);
```